# Best jQuery Mobile Page Setup

Tags: jquery, database, dynamic, mobile

I'm starting to develop a mobile version of a website that we run. Our chosen framework is jQuery Mobile since it's got a lot of promise and is moving at a pretty impressive rate.

Before I start I'd like to get a few suggestions about the best way to setup the page layout.

We know that on the "home screen" there will be four links to separate "pages". The points I'm most interested in, is whether these pages should be created on request, or loaded with the home screen content?

The next question is how the sub-pages should be linked. One of home screen pages will have a sub-menu of three more links. One of these sub-sub-pages then has a list which *again* will link to another page.

Obviously I can't have all of the content being loaded at once, and it'd be awesome if I could get each one of these to save state (since the data would be pulled in from a database). So what's the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to load the additional pages on request, you can always load them immediately after loading the first screen but then it would be terrible on users who are on limited data plan.

If a user visits homepage and quits, then all the additional information loaded would still account for his data and yet would be wasted.

What I suggest

1. Load Homepage
2. Set JS timeout of 5secs
3. Load other pages into separate divs as screens

when navigating, all you need is to switch screens instead of switching pages. You should not load more than one level of pages at a given time.

Comment: Would you suggest complete page changes, or make use of the AJAX page system jQM provides?

Comment: I suggest Ajax to load all links on same level or 1 level deep. DONT load them on click, rather load them after 5sec delay of pageload. You don't need to use Ajax page system of jQM. You can implement it directly via jquery and use jQM only for transitioning between screens

Comment: That makes sense! What about the dynamic content from generated list items? How would you suggest being able to store the current "item" page so you can link back to it or whatever?

Comment: your address bar would anyways be hidden, so use a she bang (#!) for storing prev. page id in url

Comment: But there are two values to store at once. And these would be dynamically linked by the lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch screen"? I can only find `switchPage`

Answer (score 1):

As the pages does not seem to contain much data, I think it would be better to load them on request. Only data required by each page would be loaded that way. 
For the dynamic content that you want to pass along to each page, it would be ideal to do it using jQuery. For each page created, link it with a context that is passed along with the page using jQuery.